# Sales force Event Log File shows only logout and URL event types?

Tags: soql, developer-edition, eventlogfile

Salesforce Event log file only showing log out and URI Event Types. All Event Types are not showing up in Event Log File query.

QUERY:

```
SELECT EventType FROM EventLogFile
```

OUTPUT :

```
**EventType**
*Logout
URI*
```

Please guide, how to obtain all Event Types in the EventLogFile.

I am using Developer Edition (DE) account

Comment: You have to actually fire events of other types for it to contain any other values. If you export a Report, does it still contain only those three?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the picklist values from the metadata using describes.

```
Set<String> eventTypes = new Set<String>();
for (PicklistEntry entry : EventLogFile.EventType.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
    eventTypes.add(entry.getValue());
```

They are also listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) and should have the same values:

> Event monitoring can be used with 32 different file types:
>
> - Apex Callout
> - Apex Execution
> - Apex SOAP
> - Apex Trigger
> - API
> - Async Report
> - Bulk API
> - Change Set Operation
> - Content Distribution
> - Content Document Link
> - Content Transfer
> - Dashboard
> - Document Attachment Downloads
> - Login
> - Login As
> - Logout
> - MDAPI Operation
> - Multiblock Report
> - Package Install
> - Queued Execution
> - Report
> - Report Export
> - REST API
> - Salesforce1 Adoption (UI Tracking)
> - Sandbox
> - Sites
> - Time-Based Workflow
> - URI
> - Visualforce
> - Wave Change
> - Wave Interaction
> - Wave Performance

They are also listed out [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) but with duplicates and strange formatting.